# Как перезапустить андроид приложение после его принудительной остановки?

Tags: android

Как перезапустить андроид приложение после его принудительной остановки (force stop)?

Comment: Это русскоязычное сообщество, переведите пожалуйста свой вопрос и содержимое.

Comment: Прочитайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask